# About partition the real number

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, set-theory

I know this a very simple. I want to make sure. Let $\mathcal P=\{P_\xi\colon \xi<\mathfrak c\}$ be a set of pairwise disjoint perfect sets such that $$D:=\bigcup\mathcal P$$ is meager set. So, $R\setminus D$ is co-meager and has cardinality continuum. Coonisder $$\mathcal F=\mathcal P \cup\{\{x\}\colon x\in\mathbb R\setminus D\}$$ note that $\mathcal F$ is a partition of $\mathbb R.$ So, we can enumerate $\mathcal F$ as follows $$\mathcal F=\{ A_\eta\colon \eta<\mathfrak c\}$$ Here is my easy question , every set in $\mathcal F$ even is a perfect set or a singleton. Is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have a partition of $\mathbb{R}$ into continuum-many perfect sets and continuum-many singletons, where the union of the perfect sets involved is meager.

Comment: Schwber, Tthank you. Some times I got stuck with small things